# Highlight Custom ListView Item in Loop

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Hello i want to change background of my listView item.but it only highlight on touch.but i want to change the background until i change the focus on other item. 
What i did so far is below.

Back.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

ListView

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listviewcolor"
    android:scrollingCache="false">
</ListView>
```

In Main i have tried everything but does not works it only highlight on touch.
but i want to keep highlight until i change it .

```
ListView.requestFocus();
        ListView.setActivated(true);
        ListView.setPressed(true);
        ListView.setItemChecked(4, true);
        ListView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        ListView.setSelection(2);
```

Comment: are you using custom adapters?if not better start coding one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved only by using `customAdapter` in the following way.

Initially a `Listview` will lose its focus, when user touches some other item in the layout design. One way of keeping it stay selected, even when it's out of focus is by:

1. Keeping track of selected position from `ListView`.
2. Use the selected position in the `ListView` adapter and set its view background color according to the selection.

By doing this your background color will stay selected.

Example:
**Inside your custom Adapter**:

```
Private  int studentListItemSelected;

public void ItemSelected(int itemPosition)
    {
    //This method will keep track which position of the List is Selected and the background color of it is inside this.
        this.studentListItemSelected=studentListItemSelected;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
 //layout inflation code
  if(this.studentListItemSelected==position)
{
  convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
}
else
{
 convertView.setBackgroudnColor(Color.White);
}

  return convertView;
}
```

**In your Layout Java file:**

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      adapter.ItemSelected(position);

});
```